# Why isn't Tony Stark's F.R.I.D.A.Y available offline?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In Avengers: Infinity War, it is observed that

> after following Dr. Strange being abducted by Ebony Maw into a spaceship, Tony Stark receives a phone call from Pepper Potts which loses connectivity after a few seconds of talking and his virtual assistant goes offline too. Now, I am assuming this is because of the increasing distance from earth.

Why couldn't/didn't Stark fit the virtual assistant mechanism into his already impressive nanotech powered suit?
In universe answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

My personal opinion, an A.I. assistant like FRIDAY probably requires a lot of processing power to run. I would rather have that running on a server remotely than on my local "device" because it frees up the power of my "device" to do other things. Also in case I took a rocket or whatever to just the right spot of my suit, then suddenly FRIDAY is out of commission. Stark didn't plan that he'd end up on a space ship destined for another planet so having FRIDAY running remotely presented lower risk of failure to the system in most scenarios.

And I have to throw in the out of universe explanation as well. Its a plot device and one that isn't that far fetched from our real world experience, so it fits in logically with the story.

Comment: I'd also think that because we're talking nanotech, each part of the suit must contribute processing power to the whole via a mesh network, so as the suit loses nanoparticles, it would lose processing power and eventually knock out or severely retard the AI. Remote processing would be far more reliable in that scenario.

Comment: @sanpaco Tony Stark could still have redundancies built into the system by having multiple servers with fail safes as well as one within the nano suit. Also, after the attack on New York, I'd say Tony is extremely paranoid and begins building suits for all kind of scenarios. So it's entirely likely that he considered being in space.

Comment: @Rijumone except clearly he didn't consider that scenario. Tony Stark is smart but he's also human and subject to being imperfect and making mistakes.

Comment: IDK, there are plenty of reasons I think are valid for why FRIDAY isn't an offline scenario, but suggesting Tony Stark didn't consider space, or being in space, doesn't quite sit well with me. His actions for several movies have been motivated by a focus on interstellar threats, or "that out there" being the "end game".

Comment: Plus, any offline or alternative version doesn't have to be the entire system; it can be a miniaturised offline system, e.g. not able to do internet searches, but able to handle processing HUD input etc. And I'd argue we have plenty of evidence that that is a thing, given that it would be a pretty basic requirement for his suit to function, replusors, nano-transformation, HUD etc.

Comment: @Rijumone: You've answered your own question. Tony builds multiple suits. If FRIDAY runs locally, then you have different FRIDAYs in all suits. Unless you synchronize the entire neural network for every change that occurs, but there are many technical limitations there. Secondly, there is a lot of effort and infrastructure involved in this (let alone handling synchronization errors or concurrency logic...) for what is generally considered a non-issue, since Tony has a nigh perfect connection all around the planet (I assume he owns plenty of satellites).

Comment: @DariM: Tony has executive control over his suit even without JARVIS/FRIDAY. JARVIS/FRIDAY merely exist to _supplement_ his abilities. Even if Tony considered space travel, that doesn't mean he considered space travel _only in his suit_ (with no ship nearby). Even if he considered traveling with his suit alone, maybe he simply needs an additional antenna pack which he simply doesn't carry by default, or is still in development, or... There is no reason to definitively conclude that Tony must invariably be able of space travel with full connectivity.

Comment: @Flater Tony has some control. For example, it requires FRIDAY intervention to do things like "scan" for an opponent's fight patterns (Civil War), and that's a more self-contained "library". Given that the Hulkbuster could be remote-deployed to Johannesburg, it takes suspension to believe a hypothetical extension pack couldn't be deployed in New York as he chases the spaceship. Maybe space travel wasn't possible. I think we're all agreed on the premise that he can't get 100% FRIDAY effectively offline. But limited offline functionality (on the topic) is a pretty basic design concept.